# Can Not Access Folder After Re-Installing Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, shared-folders, controlled-folder-access

On my latop I was using a windows 10, and I stopped sharing one of my folder with full of my fhoto and video archive.

Then I formatted c drive and installed a new fresh Windows 10

Now I cannot access my photos folder, because there is no valid windows user defined for it.

Even if I assign my administrator user as owner, the folder does not allow me to read, move or delete.

Are there any way to solve my conflict?

Answer (score 1):

Assigning your user to owner of the folder is not enough.  That would only allow the user to access *new* files created in the folder.  You need to propagate those permissions to all the files and sub folders.

1. Right Click on the Folder.
2. Select Properties.
3. Navigate to Security tab.
4. Press the Advanced button.
5. Press the Change Permissions.. button.
6. Give your username full control.
7. Make sure Replace all child object permissions with inheritable permissions from this object is selected.

Comment: Thank you, I will try and give feedback after it.